# Why aren't my map chunks being drawn correctly?

Tags: python, kivy, game-development

I'm trying to make a very simple game with my son in Kivy and Python.  We are trying to make our viewport (camera) centered over the player as they move around our map that is self generating.  We get the initial view, then as the player moves the initial chunk is shown in the correct place, but new chunks aren't being drawn at all.

By debugging, we can tell that we are creating chunks, that they have good values, and that our draw_chunks function knows to grab more chunks and to draw them.  They just aren't being drawn.  We think that our code for drawing the rectangles is probably wrong, but works for the initial load of the game.  We've spent a couple hours trying to fix it.  We've adjusted the viewport position a couple different ways as well as the rectangle code, but nothing seems to work.  I'm hoping someone can point out what we missed.  It is probably something very obvious or silly that we are overlooking.  Does anyone have any ideas?

```
import kivy
import random

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line, Rectangle 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window 
import enum

# Constants for the chunk size and map dimensions
CHUNK_SIZE = 48
TILE_SIZE = 16
MAP_WIDTH = 256
MAP_HEIGHT = 256

#**************************
#* Tile Int Enum Class *
#**************************
class TileEnum(enum.IntEnum):
    GRASS = 0
    DIRT = 1
    CONCRETE = 2
    ASPHALT = 3

# Class to represent the game map
class GameMap:
    def __init__(self, seed=None):
        self.seed = seed
        if seed is not None:
            random.seed(seed)
        self.chunks = {}
        self.first_chunk = False
    
    def generate_chunk(self, chunk_x, chunk_y):
        # Use the RNG to generate the terrain for this chunk
        terrain = []

        for x in range(0, CHUNK_SIZE):
            column = []
            for y in range(0, CHUNK_SIZE):
                column.append(random.randint(0, 3))
            terrain.append(column)
        
        return terrain
    
    def get_chunk(self, chunk_x, chunk_y):
        # Check if the chunk has already been generated
        if (chunk_x, chunk_y) in self.chunks:
            print("found it",chunk_x, chunk_y)
            return self.chunks[(chunk_x, chunk_y)]
        else:
            # Generate the chunk and store it in the chunk cache
            chunk = self.generate_chunk(chunk_x, chunk_y)
            self.chunks[(chunk_x, chunk_y)] = chunk
            print("made it",chunk_x,chunk_y)
            return chunk

# Class to represent the player
class Player:
    def __init__(self, pos=(0, 0)):
        self.x, self.y = pos
        self.speed = TILE_SIZE/2
    
    def move_left(self):
        self.x += self.speed
    
    def move_right(self):
        self.x -= self.speed
    
    def move_up(self):
        self.y -= self.speed
    
    def move_down(self):
        self.y += self.speed

class GameScreen(Widget):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.viewport_size = (TILE_SIZE*CHUNK_SIZE, TILE_SIZE*CHUNK_SIZE)
        self.viewport_pos = (0, 0)
        self.size = self.viewport_size

        self.map = GameMap(seed=123)
        self.player = Player((self.viewport_size[0]/2, self.viewport_size[1]/2))

        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def draw_chunks(self):
        # Determine the chunks that are currently in view
        viewport_left = int(self.viewport_pos[0] // (CHUNK_SIZE * TILE_SIZE))
        viewport_top = int(self.viewport_pos[1] // (CHUNK_SIZE * TILE_SIZE))
        viewport_right = int((self.viewport_pos[0] + self.viewport_size[0]) // (CHUNK_SIZE * TILE_SIZE))
        viewport_bottom = int((self.viewport_pos[1] + self.viewport_size[1]) // (CHUNK_SIZE * TILE_SIZE))

        print(viewport_left, viewport_top, viewport_right, viewport_bottom)
     
        # Iterate over the visible chunks and draw them
        for x in range(viewport_left, viewport_right + 1):
            for y in range(viewport_top, viewport_bottom + 1):
                chunk = self.map.get_chunk(x, y)
                #print(chunk)
                for i in range(len(chunk)):
                    for j in range(len(chunk[i])):
                        if chunk[i][j] == TileEnum.GRASS:
                            # Draw a green square for grass
                            with self.canvas:
                                Color(0.25, 0.75, 0.25)
                        elif chunk[i][j] == TileEnum.DIRT:
                            # Draw a brown square for dirt
                            with self.canvas:
                                Color(0.75, 0.5, 0.25)
                        elif chunk[i][j] == TileEnum.CONCRETE:
                            # Draw a gray square for concrete
                            with self.canvas:
                                Color(0.5, 0.5, 0.75)
                        elif chunk[i][j] == TileEnum.ASPHALT:
                            # Draw a black square for asphalt
                            with self.canvas:
                                Color(0.25, 0.25, 0.5)
                        with self.canvas:
                            Rectangle(pos=(
                                (x * CHUNK_SIZE + i) * TILE_SIZE + self.viewport_pos[0],
                                (y * CHUNK_SIZE + j) * TILE_SIZE + self.viewport_pos[1]),
                                size=(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))
    
    def draw_player(self):
        # Draw a circle for the player
        with self.canvas:
            Color(0, 0.5, 0)
            Ellipse(pos=(self.viewport_size[0]/2 - (TILE_SIZE/2), self.viewport_size[0]/2 - (TILE_SIZE/2)), size=(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))
    
    def update(self, dt):
        # Update the viewport position to keep the player centered
        self.viewport_pos = (self.player.x - self.viewport_size[0]/2, self.player.y - self.viewport_size[1]/2)
        print(self.viewport_pos)

        # Redraw the chunks and player
        self.canvas.clear()
        self.draw_chunks()
        self.draw_player()
    
    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        #print(keycode)
        if keycode[1] == 'left':
            self.player.move_left()
        elif keycode[1] == 'right':
            self.player.move_right()
        elif keycode[1] == 'up':
            self.player.move_up()
        elif keycode[1] == 'down':
            self.player.move_down()
        
# Main application class
class ProceduralGenerationGameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        
        self.title = "Procedural Generation Game"
        Config.set("graphics", "width", "768")
        Config.set("graphics", "height", "768")
        Config.set("graphics", "resizable", False)
        Config.set("graphics", "borderless", False)
        Config.set("graphics", "fullscreen", False)
        Config.set("graphics", "window_state", "normal")
        Config.set("graphics", "show_cursor", True)
        Config.write()

        window_width = Config.getint("graphics", "width")
        window_height = Config.getint("graphics", "height")

        # Create the game screen and schedule the update function to be called every frame
        game_screen = GameScreen()

        Window.size = (window_width, window_height)

        Clock.schedule_interval(game_screen.update, 1)# 1.0 / 60.0)
        
        return game_screen

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ProceduralGenerationGameApp().run()
```

Comment: We went back to a piece of paper and figured out the math.

Answer (score 1):

We updated the Rectangle code to this and reversed the players direction in his move functions:

```py
with self.canvas:
   x_chunk_offset = (x * CHUNK_SIZE * TILE_SIZE)
   y_chunk_offset = (y * CHUNK_SIZE * TILE_SIZE)
   x_tile_offset = (i * TILE_SIZE)
   y_tile_offset = (j * TILE_SIZE)
   actual_x = x_chunk_offset + x_tile_offset - self.viewport_pos[0]
   actual_y = y_chunk_offset + y_tile_offset - self.viewport_pos[1]

   Rectangle(pos=(actual_x, actual_y), size=(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))
```